# Initial View Property for PDFA

Tags: ghostscript

I am using ghostscript to convert my postscript file to PDF/A.
My requirement is to have the Initial View- Magnification property set to Fit Page.

However, the value is set to default always. I have tried different View properties in PDFMarks but none of them seems to be working.

Below is my PDFMarks:
[ /Title (Document title)  /DOCINFO pdfmark
[ /PageMode /UseOutlines /View [/Fit] /Page 1 /DOCVIEW pdfmark

I have also tried /FitV,/FitB  but none of them seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Ghostscript's pdfwrite device converts this pdfmark into an OpenAction in the Catalog. Using your pdfmark code, and an empty page, this appears to work well for me.

So the questions:

1. Which version of Ghostscript are you using
2. What is the exact command line you are sending
3. What makes you think this isn't working ? (How precisely are you
   verifying the action ?)

Comment: 1. Ghostscript version is 9.14

Comment: 2. The exact command for ps to pdf/a conversion -                                         gs -q -dPDFA=2 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sColorConversionStrategy=DeviceGray -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dDOPDFMARKS -sOutputFile=ABC.pdf PDFA_def.ps Sample.ps pdfmarks

Comment: 3. I am opening the pdf/a and manually checking the Magnification Property under Initial View Tab.

Comment: Opening with what ?

Comment: When I use Adobe Acrobat to open the file I create, using your command line, the initial view is what I expect to see. Acrobat doesn't appear to have an 'Initial View Tab'. Ghostscript 9.14 is now 2 years old, the current version is 9.19, you should try upgrading to the latest release and see if that helps.

Comment: I am using Adobe Acrobat DC to view the generated PDF/A. This has an Initial View option where i see the Magnification property set as Default.

Comment: Well I don't have DC, I'm using Acrobat X which does not have such a tab. On the other hand, it opens the file as expected. Also when I look inside the resulting PDF file it has an OpenAction in the Catalog dictionary. So, the initial view is working correctly. I suspect your problem is that you are specifying a 'PageMode', the pdfwrite device doesn't support that pdfmark, so it doesn't get written.So the PDF will open at the correct size, but without having the Outlines tab. By the way, have you tried this with the current version yet ?